# Passing a temporary by const pointer instead of const reference; is this workaround well-formed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, lifetime

Apparently, according to the C++ standard, one can't pass a const pointer to a temporary as an argument to a function, while it's totally fine to pass a const reference instead, even though both things are essentially the same.

This is puzzling, and the only explanation I have so far is that C++ can't be subtle enough to allow taking temporary's address as long as said address doesn't outlive the expression. We can trick it into allowing this, though. My question is, will it still be a well-formed program?

Here's the code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string const * constRefToPtr( std::string const & v )
{
  return &v;
}

void takeStringPtr( std::string const * s )
{
  std::cout << *s << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  // This one isn't allowed by the standard
  // takeStringPtr( &std::string( "Hello, world" ) );

  // However, this is just fine, apparently. Is this a well-formed program though?
  takeStringPtr( constRefToPtr( std::string( "Hello, world" ) ) );

  return 0;
}
```

As you can see, we're introducing a helper to convert a const reference to a const pointer. As far as I can tell, since the temporary should survive until the end of the expression, this is a well-formed program. Am I right?

If I am, is there such a helper in the standard library already?

P.S. In case you are wondering why I need this in the first place, I have a function which takes a const pointer instead of a const reference because it allows passing `nullptr`. I'd still like to be able to pass temporaries to it, though.

Comment: It is well formed. In std, [`std::addressof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) is deleted on purpose.

Comment: Wow. So they disallowed taking the address directly, but introduced a helper instead? Why? Can't they just simply allow the former thing? Is it because of the const? Ok, I think I get it now :)

Comment: They did not. Unfortunately the language allows overloading `operator&`, so `&x` might not be the address of `x`...

Comment: The function also disallows to take address of temporary.

Comment: What happens if you store the returned address in the caller? A dangling pointer. Now you are just corrupting th stack and random behavior rooted in UB occurs. You shouldn't even store a reference to a member of a an rvalue.

Comment: Well, C++ *is* like that. You can store a `string_view` to a temporary string, for example. The fact that you can doesn't mean that you should.

Comment: I usually write this as `template<class T> constexpr T& unmove(T&& x) noexcept { return (T&) x; }` and `takeStringPtr(&unmove(std::string("Hello, world!")))`. I've only had this be useful for C APIs that take pointers (where in C you would use a compound literal). For a C++ functions, you should just make an overload/helper `void function(const std::string& s) { return function(&s); }`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47458206/5754656

Comment: @Artyer thanks for the link, and your approach makes the most sense in the end (I also find the name `unmove` quite fitting). Unfortunately, the overload approach doesn't work when the function takes several of those pointers as parameters at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> this is a well-formed program. Am I right?

It is indeed well formed.

> is there such a helper in the standard library already?

It would be [`std::addressof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof), but the overload for temporary (rvalue) is deleted on purpose (to have similar restriction than `&temporary()`).

Comment: If the program is well-formed, why do they force me to make the helper? This is really puzzling

Comment: It looks well, but subverts the rules.

Comment: Not sure what your point is. If it's well-formed, then it's the rule which doesn't make sense, isn't it?

Comment: Those constructs are dangerous, split the line to add a intermediate variable (to increase readability) would make the program ill-formed with dangling pointer. some API try to be as safe as possible.

Comment: So? A lot of C++ constructs are dangerous like that, C++ doesn't define itself like a safe language. Rather than that, some behaviors are defined, while some aren't.

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ doesn''t track lifetime (contrary to Rust) in the type system. there are trade of to do between safety and possible usage...

Comment: You still have the liberty to create your unsafe function. I think it is good to try to limit dangerous API. Most of those dangerous constructs inherit from history...

Comment: @Red.Wave I've notced that you have a lot of good points. Why not make those into answers?

Comment: Btw, you don't even need a helper function, adding an intermediate cast does the trick as well - `takeStringPtr( &( std::string const & ) std::string( "Hello, world" ) );`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I can't find the exact reference documents. I try to get the best from C++. Sometimes There are stupid mistakes in my code too. An answer needs more meat. A lot of time I see good answers that just need some polishing and adding a duplicate answer seems just arrogant. Why is returning a reference or address to a temporary bad? It ends up dangling. Why is it possible to adhoc? A lot of reasons.